# Sending a request to /adCreativesV2 entity doesn't return all the fields

Tags: linkedin-api

We are in the process of designing a custom build report for our client and have recently stumbled upon a behavior which we could not puzzle. Basically, we are not getting returned the following fields

**ad_creative_name**

**ad_creative_text**

**ad_creative_title**

when sending a GET request as follows:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/136236994?projection=(*,reference~(*))`

We're getting a 200 OK response as per below:

```
    "variables": {

        "data": {

            "com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredInMailCreativeVariables": {

                "content": "urn:li:adInMailContent:5139314"

            }

        }

    },

    "test": false,

    "servingStatuses": [

        "RUNNABLE"

    ],

    "type": "SPONSORED_INMAILS",

    "version": {

        "versionTag": "6"

    },

    "reference": "urn:li:adInMailContent:5139314",

    "changeAuditStamps": {

        "lastModified": {

            "time": 1624098658000

        },

        "created": {

            "time": 1624035613000

        }

    },

    "review": {

        "reviewStatus": "APPROVED"

    },

    "campaign": "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:179783044",

    "reference!": {

        "message": "Unsupported URN domain: li:adInMailContent",

        "status": 501

    },

    "id": 136236994,

    "status": "ACTIVE"

}
```

From the response, you may also notice that we are also getting this warning

**"message": "Unsupported URN domain: li:adInMailContent",**

**"status": 501**

We've tried different API requests variations, including specifying different creatives that are active, but to no avail. Also, we were not able to find any info regarding the error above, so we are uncertain what might be causing it.

Thanks!